# if else condition in windows phone 7

Tags: c#

I am trying to do something like a if else condition in C#.

My below code is to check that all the text in text block is correct and show a display message.

```
if ((correctAns.Contains(textBlock1.Text)) && 
    (correctAns.Contains(textBlock2.Text)) && 
    (correctAns.Contains(textBlock3.Text)) && 
    (correctAns.Contains(textBlock4.Text)) && 
    (correctAns.Contains(textBlock5.Text)))
  {
      //If it contains the correct answer
      MessageBox.Show("All correct");
  }
```

What i want for now is to check if any 3 of the text in the text block is correct will show a message box.

How should i go about doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count them.

If your code matches the entire problem, this is probably the most straight-forward - but if the number of text blocks grow, you might want to re-think the solution:

```
int count = 0;

if (correctAns.Contains(textBlock1.Text)) count++;
if (correctAns.Contains(textBlock2.Text)) count++;
if (correctAns.Contains(textBlock3.Text)) count++;
if (correctAns.Contains(textBlock4.Text)) count++;
if (correctAns.Contains(textBlock5.Text)) count++;

if (count >= 3)
{
   MessageBox.Show("At least 3 correct");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It might be easier to put all the textboxes in an array and use Linq to count:

```
if (textboxes.Where(tb => correctAns.Contains(tb.Text)).Count() >= 3)
{
    // show message
}
```

This way it is much easier to add or remove textboxes to this check.

Comment: This answer would make it much easier to handle the data more than once in the same class & namespace, however, @Erno may be good to add demonstration to show him how to add them into an array just in case :)

Comment: How to add the textboxes to an array depends a lot on the current structure of the program. @ben tan: feel free to ask help.

Comment: Good point, just thought a short demo could help a bit, either way if he needs it he will ask.

Comment: @ben tan: no problem feel free to ask any clarification

Answer (score 3):

If you want any three in any combination, writing out a single conditional block to cover everything will be pretty rigid and non-flexible. It will be better to count them, then check the count.

```
int count = 0;
if (correctAns.Contains(textBlock1.Text))
    ++count;
if (correctAns.Contains(textBlock2.Text))
    ++count;
if (correctAns.Contains(textBlock3.Text))
    ++count;
if (correctAns.Contains(textBlock4.Text))
    ++count;
if (correctAns.Contains(textBlock5.Text))
    ++count;

if (count >= 3) {
    // Show message.
}
```